# Isolated Azure Function throwing error on startup

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-functions-isolated

I'm working on converting all of our c# Azure functions to be isolated from in-process but am running into an error that I can't find any information on.  The error I am getting on startup is:

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.RegisterDefaultConverters(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'.

My Program.cs couldn't be simpler I don't think:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

My .csproj has more extensions than I need but been throwing extensions at it to see if anything changes:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.Functions.Worker" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0-preview4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Warmup" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" />    
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such exceptions usually denote a package version mismatch (especially when breaking changes are not handled correctly), in this particular case  `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` is the guilty one - update it (it seems that one of the dependencies has removed the `RegisterDefaultConverters` extension method,
also it seems that `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` can be/needs to be updated also):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.13.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.9.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I scaled back on my package references and everything started working.  Still don't understand what the error means

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" />
```